# SELECT MAX(value) from table VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this table that contains multiple values all ranging from 1 to 3000, but it keep retuning `false`.

What is going wrong here?

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Server=**; Uid=**; Pwd=**; Database=**"
Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
        With sqlCommand
            .CommandText = "SELECT MAX(CAST(points AS UNSIGNED)) FROM score"
            .Connection = SQLConnection
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text

        End With
        Try
            SQLConnection.Open()
            Using reader As MySqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader
                While (reader.Read())
                    label1.Text = reader.Read()
                End While
            End Using

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        Finally
            SQLConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Using

End Using
```

Comment: you dont need a reader, just `ExecuteScalar()`;  your SQL selects ONE item, your first `reader.Read` reads that value (but you did nothing with it), since there is ONE item, the next `.Read` returns false because there is nothing else to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Read()` advances to the next row/result (and returns a boolean indicating if you've passed the end of the result set); you're looking for `GetInt32()` or similar methods.

Comment: How do I use it? Have never used this before

Comment: `label1.Text = reader.GetString(0)` `0` is the field index, if you had selected MAX and MIN, in that order, `reader.GetString(1)` would get you the MIN value.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to read the field not calling again Read

```
label1.Text = reader(0).ToString()
```

However, to read a scalar value like you do, it is preferable to use the [ExecuteScalar](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) method. It returns just the single value of your query without creating an `MySqlDataReader` and all the infrastructure needed when you want to read more than one record one by one

```
Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = "SELECT MAX(CAST(points AS UNSIGNED)) FROM score"
        .Connection = SQLConnection
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text

    End With
    Try
        SQLConnection.Open()
        Dim result = Convert.ToInt64(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar())
        label1.Text = result.ToString()
        .....
```